# How to make non editable filter in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have "country_name" filter on world bank dashboard. I saved it as with preselect_filters as "United States" now i don't want anyone to change it. Can anybody help how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter `country_name` in the chart settings instead of using a Filter box chart.